# .NET DLL Runtime referencing development solution file paths

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've developped a .NET 4.0 WPF application using log4Net logging.

On a production environment, where the app is deployed in Windows Program Files special folder, exceptions from this application are logged when catched, and their stack message reference the path of my files on the development environment (D:\DEV2015\MYAPP\Class1.cs).

```
  _logger.ErrorFormat("{0}:{1}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), e);
```

I don't understand what is going on with my application build, and why the built DLL are holding the absolute pathing as some kind of reminder,

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm guessing you probably deployed your PDB to the deployment path?

Comment: Nope, I've cleaned-up binaries output directories of pdb files before packaging and shipping the software product, and these files are not included in my Installshield deployment project installation table anyway.